# Создание дочерних\вложенных\ процессов?

Tags: c#, c++, процесс

Пишу небольшую программку которая будет открывать несколько других. Те в свою очередь уже будут заниматься своими делами. Не суть. Как сделать чтобы дочерние процессы открывались вложенными в основную программку в диспетчере задач. Понятнее на скринах.[image: Запуск дочерней программы]

[image: Как они стартуют]

[image: Как нужно]

Comment: А вы попробуйте просто не завершать Start до конца работы ваших экземпляров MyProgram.

Comment: Не помогло. Проблема осталась.

Comment: @ModNick приведите [mcve]

Comment: А вы такое видели, наверное, у svchost?

Comment: Запускаете с помощью CreateProcess или exec, а не  system.